How to do a PublishRequest with multiple MessageAttributes? (.NET)
I'm trying to run a test for a project using AWS SNS but I'm a little lost using filters:
foreach (var hobby in attributes)
{
    publishRequest.MessageAttributes.Add("Hobbies", new MessageAttributeValue
    {
        DataType = "String",
        StringValue = hobby
    });
}


// Publish the message to the topic
await _snsClient.PublishAsync(publishRequest);

Using this JSON as my request:
{
  "Body": "Hello subscribers!",
  "Subject": "New Content for users Available ",
  "Attributes":["Games","Coffee"]
}

I get the following exception:

System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Hobbies

My subscribers filter policy look like this:
  "Hobbies": [
    "Travel",
    "Home",
    "Coffee"
  ] 

How could I send the email for the subscribers that have the Attributes the request send me?
